# Can I use Django framework w/o using templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am learning how to use the Django framework, and as I am learning about Django's template system, I was wondering, if it would be possible for me to use Django without using templates to render the necessary html documents from views? As an alternative to Django's template system, I would prefer to use JavaScript in order to make the necessary data queries from the sites database(s).

This might seem counter productive, but in my opinion, I would prefer to learn the traditional front-end web stack (HTML, CSS, JS), and solidify my skills this way before going down the journey of template systems. At this point, I would be using Django only as a back-end until I was ready to incorporate templates into my dev process.

I have tried to use Django's template system, but It's a little comprehensive to learn on top of HTML and CSS at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly, it is possible to use Django without utilizing its template system for rendering HTML documents from views. In fact, integrating Django with a JavaScript framework is a common practice in web development.

You will need to find a way to make the frontend framework (usually Javascript based) with the backend, though. The most commonly used method is to implement REST API endpoints in your Django project and consume them from the frontend.

Django does not come with built-in REST API support, but you can use a third party one, such as [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) or [Django Ninja](https://django-ninja.rest-framework.com/).

Comment: Yes This is the the better way . Use Django Rest Framework (DRF) to build JSON-based RESTful APIs. DRF allows you to create, update, delete, and display data as JSON, which you can then consume and manipulate on the frontend using JavaScript. You can use it without frontend framwork too but it's goona be bit complicated.

Comment: @Starwolf I prefer the Ninja framework these days as it it is Pydantic based (a la FastAPI) therefore requires less boilerplate code. It's also async-ready.

Comment: @Starwolf thank you guys for your response! I'll try the DRF and find a front end to consume the REST API with. This approach actually makes things easier for me as I can incorporate the mobile apps as a front end along side JavaScript front-end libraries. I wish that I asked this question before being my Django journey.